# How to log PHP messages to a debug console while debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-debugger

I want to do trace or log messages to a debug window while debugging PHP in Eclipse.

Can I do it printing to stderr or something like that? I've tried, but I don't know in which Eclipse window to look for it.

I know I can do this via watches and expressions, but it would be more agile to have it automatically printed each time I debug.

I use Eclipse with Zend Debugger and Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do is just create a text file and append your debugging log in that file.

Comment: and all the Eclipse side of this question?

Comment: dear i havent used eclipse for php . no clue about it.